# Is this an acceptable solution of Multithreaded Sorting?

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, data-structures, merge

Please look at the code and provide your comments. What I am trying to implement is a multithreaded merge sort. Can it done more parallely?

I am little bit concerned about the two 'join' calls which I have put. Since they will hamper parallelism.

Following logic is used:
1) divide left array recursively using multiple threads.
2) divide right array recursively using multiple threads.
3) Wait for both threads to finish.
4) finally merge and sort everything.

```java
public class MergeSort {

static public void merge(int[] numbers, int left, int mid, int right) {
    int[] temp = new int[130];
    int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos;

    left_end = (mid - 1);
    tmp_pos = left;
    num_elements = (right - left + 1);

    while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right)) {
        if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid])
            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];
        else
            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
    }

    while (left <= left_end)
        temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];

    while (mid <= right)
        temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];

    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        numbers[right] = temp[right];
        right--;
    }
}

static public void mergeSort(final int[] numbers, final int left,
        final int right) {

    if (right > left) {
        final int mid = (right + left) / 2;
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mergeSort(numbers, left, mid);
            }
        };
        t.start();

        Thread t1 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                mergeSort(numbers, (mid + 1), right);
            }
        };

        t1.start();

        try {
            t.join();
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        merge(numbers, left, (mid + 1), right);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 67, 89, 34, 5, 56, 555, 655,
            33, 2, 34, 45, 5, 1, 2, 2334, 5, 55, 5, 577, 788, 99, 0, 9, 86,
            98, 1, 2, 3, 3, 344, 4, 3443, 343434, 34334343, 443, 3442, 55,
            6, 778, 86, 66, 67778, 8, 88, 9, 9, 999, 8, 900 };

    int len = numbers.length;
    mergeSort(numbers, 0, len - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If anything, your code is *too* parallel already ... though in a practical sense it is not really very parallel at all.

The first problem is that creating a thread is expensive.  Very expensive.  Your code is going to probably going to execute *2 (or more) orders of magnitude more* instructions creating threads than the threads will execute doing useful work.

The second problem is that no matter how many threads you create, your *actual* parallelism is going to be limited by the number of physical processors / cores on the hardware that you are using.  If there are lots more threads than cores, then most of the time threads will be sitting in a queue waiting to run.

---

If you are serious about parallel sorting, you need to read up on how to do it properly.  Just creating lots of threads (like you are currently doing) won't work.  Also, it is probably not even worth bothering to parallelise (using threads) unless you have 100,000 or more elements to sort.

References:

- [Sorting in Parallel in Java](http://rma350.scripts.mit.edu/home/?p=64)